# OpenCV: convert .raw(by photoshop cs6) to Mat return grey

Tags: opencv

I'm relatively new to OpenCV and i've stumpled upon a problem. I read the data from an .raw produced by photoshop and tried to convert it into Mat.But when I used 'imgshow' with the Mat called 'dst', the image was grey.

```
if ((err = fopen_s(&file, filename, "rb")) != 0)
    cout << err << endl;
else
    printf("The file  was opened\n");
fread(data, sizeof(char), nsize, file);
cv::Mat temp(height, width, CV_8UC1, data);    
cv::Mat mtep[3];    
temp.copyTo(mtep[0]);    
temp.copyTo(mtep[1]);    
temp.copyTo(mtep[2]);    
cv::Mat mergeM(height, width, CV_8UC3);    
merge(mtep, 3, mergeM);    
mergeM.convertTo(dst, CV_32FC3, 1/255.0);
```

Comment: You appear to have opened a file we can't see, using some code you don't show and want us to say why it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you for adding the code you use to read your file. The only remaining things we don't know are a) what your image file contains - maybe you can share via Dropbox or Google Drive, b) what `nsize`, `height` and `width` are, c) which header files you included, d) how you compiled it, e) which version of OpenCV you use...

Comment: You shouldn't be surprised your image shows up as greyscale because you only read 1 byte per pixel, i.e. a single channel from your file. You then replicated the data to have 3 identical channels which is bound to make a grey image because R=G=B. If you share the file and its dimensions, as I requested, I can likely help you.